# Html, Css issue with ul and Ll

Tags: html, css

I have created a simple website that is a set of links for me to have as a home page.

It works fine in Chrome but for some reason no matter what I do I cant get it to load correct in IE and Firefox it kind of works but not quite... see below!

[image: This is what it looks like in Chrome]

Above is what it looks like in Chrome

[image]

Above is what it looks like in IE.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Personal Homepage</title>
<style media="screen" type="text/css">
h1{
    padding-top:100px;
    padding-bottom:50px;
    font-family:"Arial Verdana", Arial, Sans-serif;}

#box {
    width: 900px;
    margin:0 auto;}

.holder {
    display: inline-block;
    background: black;
    border-radius:5px;
    margin-right:5px;
    margin-top:3px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    border-color:#666;}

.tile {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 190px;
    height: 120px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.25s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 0.25s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 0.25s linear;
    -o-transition: all 0.25s linear;
    transition: all 0.25s linear;
    border-radius:5px;}

.tile:hover {
    opacity: 0.75;}

body {
    background-color: #E6E6E6;}



</style>

</head>

<body>
<div id="box" align="center" >
<h1><a href="#" style="text-decoration: none; color:#666;" >Personal Homepage</a></h1>
    <ul>
    <li class="holder"><a class="tile" style="background-image: url(images/snow.png)" href="#"></a></li>
    <li class="holder"><a class="tile" style="background-image: url(images/updates.png)"href="#"></a></li>
    <li class="holder"><a class="tile" style="background-image: url(images/thehub.png)" href="#"></a></li>
    <li class="holder"><a class="tile" style="background-image: url(images/stats.png)"href="#"></a></li>
    <li class="holder"><a class="tile" style="background-image: url(images/shared.png)" href="#"></a></li>
    <li class="holder"><a class="tile" style="background-image: url(images/gosh.png)"href="#"></a></li>
    <li class="holder"><a class="tile" style="background-image: url(images/prudhoe.png)" href="#"></a></li>
    <li class="holder"><a class="tile" style="background-image: url(images/rowb.png)"href="#"></a></li>
    <li class="holder"><a class="tile" style="background-image: url(images/facebook.png)" href="#"></a></li>
    <li class="holder"><a class="tile" style="background-image: url(images/gmail.png)"href="#"></a></li>
    <li class="holder"><a class="tile" style="background-image: url(images/bbc.png)" href="#"></a></li>
    <li class="holder"><a class="tile" style="background-image: url(images/engadget.png)"href="#"></a></li>

    </ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

This the code I have, can anyone assist.

P.S. I have removed links and images from the code.

Comment: Offtopic: I would give you +1 for _firebox_, you made my day :D

Comment: what version of firefox and ie are you using - works fine for me in ie10 and ff 23: http://jsfiddle.net/s6X6v/, try adding `list-style:none` for the `ul` and `li`'s

Comment: IE is 9 as that's as far as the work computers can go as other applications done work on newer versions and as for ff its 24

Answer (score 0):

You need to add [reset.css](http://www.cssreset.com/) to your page, to reset native browser styles.
And if you check in IE7 and older `display: inline-block` will not work. Use IE inline-block polyfill:

```
*display: inline;
*zoom:1;
```

Comment: I tried adding both the reset.css and the *display: inline; *zoom:1; but this hasn't worked. This has messed up the central alignment and the hover doesn't work in IE now.

Answer (score 0):

here is the alter CSS,

```
<style media="screen" type="text/css">
    h1 {
    padding-top:100px;
    padding-bottom:50px;
    font-family:"Arial Verdana", Arial, Sans-serif;
}
#box {
    width: 900px;
}
.holder {
    display: inline-block;
    background: black;
    border-radius:5px;
    margin-right:5px;
    margin-top:3px;
    list-style: none;
    width: 190px;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #666;
}
.tile {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 190px;
    height: 120px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.25s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 0.25s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 0.25s linear;
    -o-transition: all 0.25s linear;
    transition: all 0.25s linear;
    border-radius:5px;
}
.tile:hover {
    opacity: 0.75;
}
body {
    background-color: #E6E6E6;
    width: 1000px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
</style>
```

Border radius wont work in older IE versions. So use this JQuery Corner plugin http://jquery.malsup.com/corner/

Altered holder class & body tag css rules.

Comment: I tried adding both the reset.css and the *display: inline; *zoom:1; but this hasn't worked. This has messed up the central alignment and the hover doesn't work in IE now.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use a reset.css style sheet.

Every browser has it's standard CSS.

So get all this CSS out u should use a reset Style sheet.

It can cause these problems sometimes.

[Style sheet to reset CSS](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)

Comment: I have tried a Reset.css but this hasn't helped. Still have the issue.

Comment: Well i had the same problem and fixed it with this css file. I would also recommend you to use your css in an other file and let your html link to that file. It looks more organised

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by simply adding 
 `<!DOCTYPE html>` to the top.

Who would have though it was so simple.